# OpenVPN left a SSL certificate… How to remove it?

Tags: ssl, openvpn, certificate

Well a while ago I tried *OpenVPN Access Point* to use my server as VPN.
Then I wanted to get letsencrypt
then everything failed
then I removed OpenVPN Access Point
then the stupid certificate is still there

I have tried purging OpenSSL... Nothing

Help...

EDIT:
This is on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial. DigitalOcean. 512MB RAM.
Also, I followed [this](https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/quick-start-guide.html).

Comment: `rm -f /where/is/certificate`

Comment: The problem is that I don't know where it is =(

Comment: But what's the problem exactly? Which sw fails due to left cert and when?

Comment: Well the main problem is that I can still access the https site (invalid certificates though, but still). While there is something there I can't install Let's Encrypt.

Comment: openvpn normally doesn't install any new cert, so your problem is somewhere else. Create a new post with the letsencrypt error message.

Comment: Can we just close this and walk away from it. The OP clearly hasn't a clue what is going on.

Comment: Sorry, I should've explained it was an OpenVPN Access Point. Didn't remember the name at the time I wrote the OP.

Comment: I know, @istheEnglishway. I am not good with servers and certificates and all this. Sorry =(

Comment: You must have created a directory try to remember how you done.

Comment: I followed this: https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/quick-start-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

For *nix systems I would try

```
cd /path/to/directory
rm certificate.file
```

For Windows I would try

```
cd \path\to\directory
del certificate.file
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know where it is =(

Comment: try looking in /etc/openvpn

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: I really have no idea what you think you're doing but it's different from what your writing.

Comment: I ran `ls /etc/openvpn`.

Answer (score 0):

Well - I am stupid...
I just **forgot to remove the `openvpn-as` package**

So
**`sudo apt purge openvpn-as`**
... Simple as that

*Sorry for being so stupid*